# How to Sum up the attribute values of objects in a list having particular IDs and assign it to another object using Streams

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

My classes.

```java
class MyLoan {
    private Long loanId;
    private BigDecimal loanAmount;
    private BigDecimal totalPaid;
    ....
}
```

```java
class Customer {
    private Long loanId;
    private List<MyLoan> myLoan;
}
```

I want to iterate over the `myLoan` from a `Customer` and calculate the `totalPaid` amount.

My logic is "If `loanId` is `23491L` or `23492L`, then add the `loanAmount` of those two `loanId`'s and set the value in the `totalPaid` amount of `loanId` `23490L`".`totalPaid` amount is  **always showing as zero** with my logic below.

And want to use Java 8 streams, but unable to write multiple conditions when using streams.

```java
BigDecimal spreadAmount;
for (MyLoan myloan: customer.getMyLoan()) {
    if (myloan.getLoanId() == 23491L || myloan.getLoanId() == 23492L) {
        spreadAmount = spreadAmount.add(myloan.getLoanAmount());
    }
    if (myloan.getLoanId() == 23490L) {
        myloan.setTotalPaid(spreadAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing two things in one loop. You should make one loop to add the numbers up, and then a second loop to find where to put the result. Both of those steps (separately) can be done with the Java 8 streaming interface. Once you break your problem down into smaller pieces, it starts to fit into the streaming model better.

Comment: *`totalPaid` amount is always **showing as zero** with my logic below* - the code you've posted will not compile because it attempts to access variable `totalPaid` before it has been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `totalPaid` field is not modified because your `MyLoan` instance with id 23490l is encountered before the other two `MyLoan`s.

As @Silvio Mayolo has suggested in the comments you should first compute the total amount with a temp variable and then assign it to the `totalPaid` field of the `MyLoan` instance with id 23490l.

This is a stream implementation of what you were trying to do:

```
//If to make sure that the element MyLoan invoking the setter is actually present
if (myLoan.stream().map(MyLoan::getLoanId).anyMatch(value -> value == 23490l)){
    myLoan.stream()
            .filter(loan -> loan.getLoanId() == 23490l)
            .findFirst()
            .get()
            .setTotalPaid(myLoan.stream()
                    .filter(loan -> loan.getLoanId() == 23491l || loan.getLoanId() == 23492l)
                    .map(MyLoan::getLoanAmount)
                    .reduce(BigDecimal.valueOf(0), (a, b) -> a = a.add(b)));
}
```

##### WARNING

The method `get()`, invoked on the `Optional` retrieved with the terminal operation `findFirst()`, could throw a `NoSuchElementException` if a `MyLoan` with id 23490l is not present within the list. You should first make sure that the element is present, as I've done with my if statement.

A second (bad practice) could involve catching the `NoSuchElementException` thrown by the `get()`, in case the desired `MyLoan` is not present. As it has been pointed out in the comments, catching a `RuntimeException` (`NoSuchElementException` is a subclass of it) is a bad practice, as we should investigate on the origin of the problem rather than simply catching the exception. This second approach was honestly a (lazy) last resort only to show another possible way of handling the case.

Comment: oh ok. It is not always that ID "23490l" is present. In many cases the ID "23490l" is not present then the above solution may not be the apt one right ?

Comment: @user8115347 The above solution is correct. You just need to add an `if (list.stream().anyMathc()){...}` to male sure that the element you're looking for is actually present before using the stream.

Comment: what is anyIDValue in the solution above?

Comment: It was meant as a parameter. In your specific case corresponds to 23490l. But you could parameterize it to whatever you want to filter for. Consequently, also the filter within the stream should be parameterized. Btw, I've replaced it with 23490l so it's easier to understand,

Comment: I'm getting the compilation error 'anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate<? super java.lang.Long>)' in 'java.util.stream.Stream' cannot be applied to '(long)'

Comment: **1.** *The aggregate operation get()* - What makes you think that `get()` is an aggregate operation? **2.** *at least handled in a try-catch block* - Do you realize that handling a RuntimeException using `try/catch` is harmful advice?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko  you're right, big distraction error... `get()` is only a method offered by the `Optional` class retrieved with the `findFirst()` **terminal** operation (not aggregate my bad). Anyway, I recommend, as my solution does, to check first with an if statement whether the element is present or not. RuntimeExceptions should be investigated rather than caught. The only reason why I mentioned it was only as a last resort (definitely not a best practice). I'll edit the answer. Thanks for letting me notice.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to fetch a *loan* for which you want to define a total paid amount. If this step succeeds, then calculate a total.

In order to find a *loan* with a particular id using streams, you need to create a stream over the *customers loans* and apply `filter()` in conjunction with `findFirst()` on it. It'll give you the *first element* from the stream that matches the predicate passed into the *filter*. Because result might not be present in the stream, `findFirst()` returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#method-summary) object.

Optional class offers a wide range of method to interact with it like `orElse()`, `ifPresent()`, `orElse()`, etc. Avoid blindly using `get()`, unless you didn't check that value is present, which is in many cases isn't the most convenient way to deal with it. Like in the code below, `ifPresent()` is being used to proceed with the logic if value is present.

So if the required loan was found, the next step is to calculate the total. Which is done by filtering out target ids, extracting amount by applying `map()` and adding the amounts together using `reduce()` as a terminal operation.

```
public static void setTotalPaid(Customer customer, Long idToSet, Long... idsToSumUp) {
    List<MyLoan> loans = customer.getMyLoan();
    getLoanById(loans, idToSet).ifPresent(loan -> loan.setTotalPaid(getTotalPaid(loans, idsToSumUp)));
}

public static Optional<MyLoan> getLoanById(List<MyLoan> loans, Long id) {
    return loans.stream()
        .filter(loan -> loan.getLoanId().equals(id))
        .findFirst();
}

public static BigDecimal getTotalPaid(List<MyLoan> loans, Long... ids) {
    Set<Long> targetLoans = Set.of(ids); // wrapping with set to improve performance
    
    return loans.stream()
        .filter(loan -> targetLoans.contains(loan.getLoanId()))
        .map(MyLoan::getLoanAmount)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```